# jquery javascript on load variable scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I am trying to get some configuration from an external js file, so it seems I need to do that within a `$(document).ready(function(){....`. The variable that holds the config object needs to be globally accessible to all functions. There isn't any reason for all functions to be within a document ready function.

From what I have read, the following should make `app.config` available globally, but it does not!

```
window.app = {};

$(document).ready(function(){
    app.config = window[$('body').attr('data-app')];
});

console.log(app.config);
```

This produces the error `app.config is undefined`. I assume the variable would be accessible globally within the document ready, but I need it to be globally available everywhere. How would I do this? If possible an explanation of scope in and out of document ready would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It isn't available until you assign it a value. You don't assign it a value until the `ready` event fires, but you look at the value immediately (at which point it is still `undefined`).

For comparison:

```
window.app = {};

$('button').on('click', function(){
    app.config = 1
});

console.log(app.config);
```

This doesn't set `config` to `1` until a button is clicked.

Same principle.

Answer (score 0):

The actual order of execution looks like this:

```
1. app = {}
2. create listener
3. console.log app.conig
4. document is ready
5. app.config is initalized
```

You call `console.log(app.config)` too early, for `app.config` to contain anything.

The better way to use config after it's initialized is the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  app.config = window[$('body').attr('data-app')]

  # you should use config only after it's initialized
  useConfig()
  # call other functions here too
})

function useConfig() {
  console.log(app.config)
}
```

Comment: showing the execution order like that is helpful, and explains why I get the problem, but not how it could be resolved. There are a lot of functions in the script that will rely on the config data, but it seems wrong to just chuck everything in the document ready function. Is there a better solution?

Comment: @Ally see my updates answer how it's better to be done

Comment: OK so any function that requires config data would have to be called within the `document.ready` function for the variable to be available to them. But what if another function outside of the `document.ready` function, calls one of the functions that requires config data? Would the variable be available then? Probably not. For now I put all functions in `document.ready` so it works, but it doesn't seem the right way some how.

Comment: @Ally there should not be any such function, which call config-dependent function before config is initialized. You should switch to this kind of thinking from what you are accustomed in "traditional" programming.

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready(function( ){});` will get fired after

```
document.onreadystatechange= function () {  
  if (document.readyState == "complete") {

  }
}.//This is one ways of implementing $(document).ready();
```

In your case your `console.log()` is getting called before the `readyState` evaluates to complete.

Answer (score -1):

It does available globally. The value of $('body').attr('data-app') is undefined probably.
Try for example:

```
window.app = {};

$(document).ready(function(){
    app.config = window['Attr'];
});

console.log(app.config);
```

Comment: The value is defined ok and works if the log is output from within the document ready function